# How to get the value of msExchMailboxGuid of an Actvie Directory user by python script

Tags: python, active-directory, win32com

I can get some attributes of an Active Directory user by python script as follows:

```
import win32com.client

ldap="SELECT cn, mail From 'LDAP://OU=XXXXXXXX,DC=center,DC=intranet,DC=sinotrans'"

c = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
c.Open('Provider=ADsDSOObject')

rs,rc = c.Execute(ldap)
rs.MoveFirst()
while not rs.EOF:
    for e in rs.fields:
        print('{}: {}'.format(e.Name, e.Value))
    print()
    rs.MoveNext()
```

But if I add "msExchMailboxGuid" to the SQL query clause, the value of msExchMailboxGuid is always .
It seems msExchMailboxGuid is not a string and how I print its value? I run the script under Python 3.2.3.
Any answer are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the below on Python 2.7, but the main idea should be the same.

The [MSDN documentation on msExchMailboxGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa564778%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) notes that it's syntax is 2.5.5.10, which, as documented [in this table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961740.aspx) is an octet string.

This seems to be represented in Python as a meaningless string of unicode characters. We can convert this to a string of hexadecimal characters using the [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) function to convert the character to an integer.

This gives us something like this:

```
import win32com.client

ldap="SELECT cn, mail, msExchMailboxGuid From 'LDAP://OU=XXXXXXXX,DC=center,DC=intranet,DC=sinotrans'"

c = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
c.Open('Provider=ADsDSOObject')

rs,rc = c.Execute(ldap)
rs.MoveFirst()
while not rs.EOF:
    for e in rs.fields:
        if e.Name != 'msExchMailboxGuid':
            print('{}: {}'.format(e.Name, e.Value))
        else:
            print('{}: {}'.format(e.Name, ''.join(['{:x}'.format(ord(x)) for x in e.Value]))
    print()
    rs.MoveNext()
```

This should output the `msExchMailboxGuid` as a hexadecimal string. To get the `msExchMailboxGuid` value displayed as a nicely-formatted GUID string, we can port the `HexGuidToGuidStr` function from [this blog post](http://clintboessen.blogspot.com/2011/03/convert-octet-string-into-readable.html) as follows:

```
def hex_to_guid(s):
   return '-'.join([
       ''.join(s[8-2*x:10-2*x]  for x in range(1, 5)),
       ''.join(s[12-2*x:14-2*x] for x in range(1, 3)),
       ''.join(s[16-2*x:18-2*x] for x in range(1, 3)),
       s[16:20],
       s[20:]
   ])
```

And wind up with:

```
import win32com.client

ldap="SELECT cn, mail, msExchMailboxGuid From 'LDAP://OU=XXXXXXXX,DC=center,DC=intranet,DC=sinotrans'"

c = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
c.Open('Provider=ADsDSOObject')

rs,rc = c.Execute(ldap)
rs.MoveFirst()
while not rs.EOF:
    for e in rs.fields:
        if e.Name != 'msExchMailboxGuid':
            print('{}: {}'.format(e.Name, e.Value))
        else:
            if e.Value is not None:
                print('{}: {}'.format(e.Name, hex_to_guid(''.join(['{:x}'.format(ord(x)) for x in e.Value]))))
    print()
    rs.MoveNext()
```

Having said all that, the `msExchMailboxGuid` may be showing up as an empty string merely because there is no value associated with the user in question. Especially if you use the code I just laid out, you'll need to handle that case specially.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I think there's a ) missed for the second print.
But it doesn't work here and I get the following message:
    print('{}: {}'.format(e.Name, ''.join(['{:x}'.format(ord(x)) for x in e.Value])))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @user1430185: I edited the code above. Note, however, if you're ending up with a value of `None`, that would tend to mean that the account does not have an `msExchMailboxGuid` value, which is quite possible... I added a check for that situation above.

Comment: That's great! I stucked here for hours. Thank you.